# JavaCV - Implementing a good descriptor matcher

Tags: image, image-processing, javacv, matcher

I'm developing a program to detect similarities between two pictures, in order to determine if they represent the same object. After studying the subject, I've determined that 3 main components are needed:

- the detector
- the extractor/descriptor
- the matcher

I've successfully implemented the first two (PM me if you need help with it, I know it can be a huge pain), but I'm having problems with the matcher. Here's a part of the code I use:

```
    DMatch matches = new DMatch();
    BFMatcher matcher = new BFMatcher(NORM_HAMMING, true);
    [...]
    matcher.match(descriptor1, descriptor2, matches, null);
    System.out.println("Matches: " + matches.capacity());
```

The output of matches.capacity() is 58, when I was hoping it would be the exact same number of keypoints or descriptor points (because I'm comparing an image to itself...). 
Am I expecting the wrong result? Am I doing something else wrong? Some help would be greatly appreciated :)

***EDIT:***

I've managed to finish my program, and can now answer to my own question, hoping it will help someone in my previous situation:

The matcher.match(...) method computes the binary strings or float vectors that describe each image (e.g. descriptor1 and descriptor2), returning the query index (index of the keypoint in keypoints1), the train index (the index of keypoints2 equivalent match for the point in queryIndex) and the hamming distance between those points. This matches every point in image 1 to every point in image 2 (at least from drawMatches, that's my conclusion), but if you want to determine a matching rate between two images, you need to filter the DMatch matches content. For this, you must create an algorithm yourself (none of the ones I found online worked well, e.g. 2*minDist).

If you need more help or some code, don't hesitate to PM me. I know how frustrating it can be to understand this whole image matching process!

Comment: I will take a bit of guess here and postulate that your descriptor match algorithms follows [Lowe's SIFT paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/) and only returns key-point matches for which the second best match was at least, say 60 percent worse.

Comment: I'm using the FAST detector + FREAK descriptor. I've recently learned that I can only use the Hamming distance to calculate matches. Am I missing a step here? And what you are telling me is that I need to change my parameters?

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `matches.size()` to obtain the *effective* number of matches found (`capacity` gives the internal array allocated size).

Comment: matches.sizeof() always returns 1...wich leads me to believe that there is no matching at work here at all

Comment: You mean `matches.size()`? Anyway you should not use `capacity` as detailed above. Perhaps you have another problem (e.g. with your input parameters, etc). I recommend use to visualize the outputs e.g. via `Features2d.drawMatches` to make sure everything works as expected.

Comment: JavaCV does not show the .size() method for a DMatch variable...only sizeof(). I'll try drawing the matches to better visualize the results. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Shouldn't you use a `MatOfDMatch matches` to hold the list of pairs (see `Features2dTest.java` or `BruteForceDescriptorMatcherTest.java`)? This can be converted to an array of `DMatch` (`DMatch adm[] = matches.toArray()`).

Comment: MatOfDMatch doesn't even exist...and those classes you said would be very helpful, apart from the fact half those methods aren't recognized by my Java version at all

Comment: Hence the misunderstanding!... On my own I was referring to OpenCV trunk version (which is 2.4.x). These APIs are available within OpenCV v2.4.2 which is the latest stable release.

Comment: I've downloaded the trunk version from the openCV dev zone, using GIT. Everything's the same though(I've replaced the original openCV folder). Am I doing something wrong?